# How does $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr B'$ are equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

> Let  $\mathscr T$ and $\mathscr T'$   be topologies on $X$ generated
>   by $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr B'$ respectively.    By Archimedean
>   property I can prove that  $ \forall \epsilon>0$ there exists  $N
>  \in\mathbb N$ such that  $1/N <ϵ $.$\forall x\in X ,B(X;1/N)\subset
>  B(X;\epsilon)$. So, $\mathscr T'$ is finer than $\mathscr T$ by

[image]
)

> How do I prove $\mathscr T$ is finer than $\mathscr T'$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

If $B\in\mathscr B'$  then $B\in \mathscr B$ because you can choose $\varepsilon=1/n$.

Comment: okay. I understood. thank you